# what does signature in R mean?

Tags: r, signature

HI I was reading [this doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf) and it says

> rules-class
>
> coerce signature(from = "rules", to = "data.frame"); represents the
>   set of rules as a data.frame

Does this mean I can write code this?

```
coerce(object_of_rules_class, from = 'rules', to = 'data.frame')
```

What does signature mean - some simple example please? Thanks-

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but the term "signature" typically refers to how the function is called (which positional and named arguments are provided)

Comment: thank you @PaulH - would you expect the above code that I guessed too?

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best definition is provided in ["How S4 Methods Work" by J. Chambers, p.2](https://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf): a signature is "a named list of classes, with the names corresponding to the formal arguments of the function". That is to say, it specifies the classes of the arguments.

If I understood it correctly, the code you mentioned means the function will coerce the passed argument (an object of class 'rules') into an object of class 'data.frame' before actually being used by the function.